# Why couldn’t declaratory reliefs in U.S. courts be used as a way forward to stop law-enforcement violence and overturn “qualified immunity”?

Tags: united-states, federal-courts, case-law, law-enforcement, qualified-immunity

Summary of judgement is easier to achieve for civil remedies against claims against the law enforcement since a very narrow construction is used for a wrong having to match the facts of a previously ruled case. Therefore, challenging qualified immunity on a case by case basis is probably not very effective that way.

But if a case is considered on the merits, and cannot be thrown out, a judge may get a chance to reach a finding that a certain action would be in violation of the law and/or the constitution, and next time, that declaratory relief could be used (by an estoppel, or as case law if on appeals).

**Questions:**

Is this a valid strategy to set get decisions on undecided cases to prevent them from reoccurring?

If not, is it because non-appellate courts decisions may only have an (judicial, collateral etc.) estoppel effect and won’t become binding law, and law enforcement agencies would rather not challenge district courts decision?

If not this, what is the reason? Or has a strategy like this been used to draw the boundaries of law enforcement operatives?

**Law enforcement violence** as used in this question should be read as the willful use of unnecessary or excessive violence or force under for e.g. such that would be in violation of the International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights (the "ICCPR") as understood by customary international law or binding precedent of international courts.

From the Wikipedia on the compliance of the U.S. with the ICCPR:

> "In 1994, the [UN]'s Human Rights Committee expressed concerns with compliance [by the U.S.]:
>
> Of particular concern are widely formulated reservations which essentially render ineffective all Covenant […] rights which would require any change in national law to ensure compliance with Covenant obligations. No real international rights or obligations have thus been accepted. […]
>
> Indeed, the [U.S.] has not accepted a single international obligation required under the Covenant. It has not changed its domestic law to conform with the strictures of the Covenant. Its citizens are not permitted to sue to enforce their basic human rights under the Covenant. It has not ratified the Optional Protocol to the Convention against Torture (OPCAT). As such, the Covenant has been rendered ineffective, with the bone of contention being United States officials' insistence upon preserving a vast web of sovereign, judicial, prosecutorial, and executive branch immunities that often deprives its citizens of the "effective remedy" under law the Covenant is intended to guarantee.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "law enforcement violence".

Comment: Added a working definition.

Comment: Are you suggesting that qualified immunity laws are unconstitutional?

Comment: The first part of your definition is already part of US law, so you specifically mean "changing the standard to one used outside the US legal system".  So now there are three completely different balls in the air. I just want to make sure I understand what you're asking – though I suggest separating the issues.

Comment: The question would probably not allow for a sound interpretation if challenging the standard to the standard currently applied; it definitely needs a standard uninfluenced by the interest of the government, therefore, I pointed, as a matter of example, to one that could serve well as the basis. Customary international law would be so moot that many would argue doesn't impose a higher standard. ICCPR does appear to. Death resulting by the actions of law enforcement is highest in the U.S. among nations of the West. We see people kneeled on their necks 9 mins in broad day light. Something's off.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Please help me understand what allows for such a reading so that I can correct it.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Also, the Constitution is what the SCOTUS says it is; I'm sure they made sure to first explain that QI is not, and now it is Constitutional. (See from the source by user6726: "Erwin Chemerinsky, Dean of Berkeley Law, cites Cato Institute’s stance against qualified immunity at the event, "How the Supreme Court Empowers Police & Subverts Civil Rights") I personally lean to believe scholars over people in power.

Comment: Erwin Chemerinsky lead the advisory team of the plaintiff in _Johnson v. Ford_ (2005), too, a major case on punitive damages, an impeccable moral character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can start [here](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/declaratory_judgment), with the fact that "A declaratory judgment is a binding judgment from a court defining the legal relationship between parties and their rights in a matter before the court". It is a means for parties to resolve an actual controversy, so it precedes the proposed action. The scenario that eventually develops into Jones v. State involves law enforcement officers preventing Jones from acting unlawfully, and the question that the officer must consider is whether the statutory authorization of force that he contemplates using is "allowed" in the relevant legal sense. Unless Jones and the officers seek to make a court case out of a certain action and response, this can't be decided before the fact, and a declaratory judgment is inappropriate (indeed, inconceivable).

Whether or not a particular level of force is legal in law enforcement is determined by whether or not the government enforcers have been put on notice that an action is illegal. See [Pierson v. Ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierson_v._Ray) and subsequent rulings. A challenge to the doctrine of qualified immunity is certainly a possibility ([Cato](https://www.cato.org/qualified-immunity) has a campaign), but it is the law of the land at least right now. [Various cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualified_immunity#Challenges_to_qualified_immunity) have tuned up the perimeters of qualified immunity, but I don't see any serious prospects for simply "cancelling" QI.

As you presumably know, the position of the various levels of government in the US which might be accused of allowing excess force dispute that claim, instead holding that the level of force use *is* necessary and in conformity with international law (or: the enforcer does not have qualified immunity). However, an appeal to foreign rulings *could* interact with the doctrine of [qualified immunity.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/qualified_immunity) A suit would be allowed if an action violates a clearly established statutory or constitutional right – limiting the scope of inquiry to determination of US constitutional rights. To connect judgment under international law to qualified immunity, the courts would simply have to expand the set of rights determiners, to include "customary international law" and "binding precedent of international courts". Of course, that takes us vastly beyond the realm of the imaginable under US law.
Use of force in the US *is*, abstractly, limited to that which is objectively reasonable and necessary in the circumstances confronting the officer. As a starter, though, you could propose a change in the use of firearms, such that firearms cannot be used to effect an arrest, and can only be used in self defense or defense of others against imminent death or injury. I believe that that standard exists "elsewhere", but not in the US. This is a standard that could in principle be adopted by the various legislatures.

Comment: "[T]he question that the officer must consider is whether the statutory authorization of force that he contemplates using is "allowed" in the relevant legal sense. Unless Jones and the officers seek to make a court case out of a certain action and response, this can't be decided before the fact, and a declaratory judgment is inappropriate (indeed, inconceivable)." Qualified immunity can prevent the suit from moving forward for new decisional law be established absent prior precedent (also inconceivable chicken-and-egg situation) The immunity does not stop actions for declaratory relief.

Comment: "However, an appeal to foreign rulings could interact with the doctrine of qualified immunity." As a matter of persuasive authority? "[the doctrine] in conformity with international law", right, the ones the U.S. selectively agreed to allow it to leak into its domestic dealings.

Comment: "As a starter, though, you could propose a change in the use of firearms, such that firearms cannot be used to effect an arrest, and can only be used in self defense or defense of others against imminent death or injury." Such a strict rule is not present, probably other than in the UK (many don't even carry a firearm). But even where there are guns with the police, somehow they are almost never fired. When they are, that is national news. The rule probably leans back to when you can actually use force. Intelligent  handcuffs could be used at gunpoint, no physical contact.